# Why use foreach to get attachment_id if numberposts is equal to 1?

Tags: post-thumbnails, php

I needed to pass an image to a Pinterest plugin in posts without a Featured Image so I wrote a little function to get the id of the first picture in a post.  This code is in the `loop-single.php` where the sharing buttons are located.

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $thumb_for_pinterest = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );
} else {
    $attachments = get_children( array(
        'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(),
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'numberposts'    => 1, // show all -1
        'post_status'    => 'inherit',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'orderby'        => 'menu_order ASC'
    ) );

    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
        $thumb_for_pinterest = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'full' );
    }
}
```

My question is this: why do I need to use a `foreach` to get the `attachment_id`?
Specifically, what is this line doing?

```
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {...
```

I believe an associative array is being returned with only 1 object in it.  However, when I tried to just pop the object out of the array and use it I got lots of errors.  Only by putting it in the `foreach` could I get the image id out.

Is there an easier way to get the `attachment_id` of the first image in a post?

I have read a lot of questions and googled this quite extensively, but couldn't understand it completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`get_children`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children) will return

> an associative array of posts [...] with post IDs as **array keys**, or an empty array if no posts are found.

---

This statement `$attachment_id => $attachment` is the same as the more commonly used `$key => $value`.

Using this command `echo '<pre>'.print_r($attachments,true).'</pre>';` we get the following:
<sup>resumed version of a `get_children` with `numberposts => 2`</sup>

```
Array
(
    [83] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 83
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2012-06-22 05:06:22
            [post_content] => 
            [post_title] => barajas
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => inherit
            [post_name] => barajas-4
            [post_modified] => 2012-06-22 05:06:22
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2012-06-22 05:06:22
            [post_parent] => 28
            [guid] => http://wp00.dev/wp-content/uploads/barajas3.jpg
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => attachment
            [post_mime_type] => image/jpeg
        )

    [180] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 180
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2012-06-30 04:18:06
            [post_content] => 
            [post_title] => Yuri Atom_00281
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => inherit
            [post_name] => yuri-atom_00281
            [post_modified] => 2012-06-30 04:18:06
            [post_parent] => 28
            [guid] => http://wp00.dev/wp-content/uploads/Yuri-Atom_00281.jpg
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => attachment
            [post_mime_type] => image/jpeg
        )

)
```

So, `[83]` and `[180]` are the ***$key*** and `stdClass Object` is their ***$value***.
I think when calling `get_children` a foreach is almost mandatory, and this will be clear next...

---

If you use [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) with exactly the same arguments, the result will be *exactly* the same except for one difference, the returned array will have numeric sequential keys:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 83
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2012-06-22 05:06:22
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 180
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2012-06-30 04:18:06
        )
)
```

---

All that being said, if you use `get_posts` and `numberposts => 1`, you can substitue the `foreach` block for:

```
$thumb_for_pinterest = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachments[0]->ID, 'full' );
```

---

With `get_children` **we don't know** what's the `$key` number, as it is the same as the Attachment ID, hence the foreach...

But with a regular numeric key (0, 1, 2, 3... etc), you can drop the `foreach` and call the first element of the array directly (`$attachments[0]`) and its object element (`->ID`).

Comment: Thanks.  One of the best answers I have seen. Make so much more sense.